# Управление ScrollBar на C#  в Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, c#

Мне требуется, чтобы при изменении программно текста TextBox'а скроллбар не двигался в самый верх. Хотя бы как задать его координату програмно и возвратить текущее положение. Как работает свойство TextBox'а, AutoScrollOffset вообще не понятно.

мой TextBox представляет собой длинный список изменяющихся во времени без участия пользователя величин в виде  длинной длинной вертикальной полосы. и хотелось бы передвинуть скролл например в середину списка и чтоб он там и оставался.

Comment: Очень интересный вопрос. Жду ответа.

P.S. А зачем в тегах вопроса "с"?

Comment: речь о WPF или Forms ?

Comment: речь о WinForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для управления ScrollBar можно использовать API функции:

```
//типы ScrollBar-ов
private const int SB_HORZ = 0x0;
private const int SB_VERT = 0x1;

//WM - сообщения
private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;
private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

//Комманды для ScrollBar-а
private const int SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4;

//Получении позиции
//Возвращает насколько я понял верхнюю видимую строку TextBox-а
//nBar = тип ScrollBar
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);

//Установка позиции бегунка на ScrollBar-е
//nBar = тип ScrollBar
//nPos = строка
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);

//PostMessage, необходима для установки позиции в TextBox-е
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool PostMessageA(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int wParam, int lParam);

//Пример
private void test()
{
    //Получаем актуальную позицию ScrollBar-а TextBox-а
    int originalLine = GetScrollPos(textBox1.Handle, SB_VERT);

    //Ставим бегунок ScrollBar-a, будто верхняя видимая строка у нас восьмая
    SetScrollPos(textBox1.Handle, SB_VERT, 8, true);

    //Прокручиваем TextBox к восьмой строке
    PostMessageA(textBox1.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_THUMBPOSITION + 0x10000 * 8, 0);

}
```

Документация:

- [SetScrollPos](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetScrollPos.html)
- [GetScrollPos](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetScrollPos.html)
- [PostMessage](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/PostMessage.html)
- [ScrollBar константы](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.ScrollBarConstants)
- [ScrollBar commands](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.ScrollBarCommands)
- [WM-константы](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.WindowsMessages)

Answer (score 0):

Если изменять не `Text`, а `SelectedText`, то скроллиться будет на место изменения. Например, так можно добавить текст и ускроллить в конец:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
textBox1.SelectedText += "ahaha haha";
```

Comment: это не подходит , так как текстбокс у меня  чисто для просмотра , не редактируемый и курсор туда ставить вообще не хочу , нужно чтоб можно было прокрутить до нужной величины и видеть как она изменяется во времени .

Comment: ок, советую отразить это в вопросе